# What does "User-agent: * Disallow: /" mean?

Tags: robots.txt

On a /robots.txt page, what does this mean?

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

Does this mean that you cannot search and get results of this website on a search engine? For example does it block Google?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: By very careful with the disallow directive. I wanted to block the Wayback machine bot with `User-agent: ia_archiver`
`Disallow: /` which should only block this one search bot, but this ended up blocking the Google bot completely. I added those lines as an extra entry at the end of the robots.txt file: `User-agent: Googlebot` `Allow: /` which seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

It blocks (good) bots (e.g, Googlebot) from indexing any page.

From [this page](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html):

> The "User-agent: *" means this section applies to all robots. The
>   "Disallow: /" tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on
>   the site.
>
> There are two important considerations when using /robots.txt:
>
> - robots can ignore your /robots.txt. Especially malware robots that
>     scan the web for security vulnerabilities, and email address
>     harvesters used by spammers will pay no attention.
> - the /robots.txt file is a publicly available file. Anyone can see what sections of
>     your server you don't want robots to use.

Comment: do note though, that either malicious, or poorly coded bots may go ahead and index the page anyways.

Comment: @user2366842 I believe I sufficiently covered that.

Comment: looks like your edit took place right before my post.

Answer (score 4):

See the [robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html).

`User-agent: *` matches every bot that supports robots.txt (and hasn’t a more specific record in the same file, e.g. `User-agent: BotWithAName`).

`Disallow: /` forbids those bots to crawl anything on your host.

Note that not all bots support and respect a robots.txt file.